# Is calling another action in store listener an anti-pattern for Flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux, alt.js

In my codebase, I fire action(s) inside some store listeners.
However, I've heard recently that this is a bad practice.
Why is it bad and how should I fix or refactor it? 
I've done research on this issue but wasn't able to find a good example.

FYI, to fire action(s), I use `action.defer` provided by [Alt.js](http://alt.js.org/docs/actions/).

Comment: Sounds like a violation of event based promise idiom.  Completion of the listener task could fire a subsequent event, to be picked up by other listeners.  You need to write as if it were single threaded code.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a valid Flux pattern, however when the function that handles actions is firing another action, it easily becomes a bug spot on your code, and it becomes difficult to track the bug.

---

How to refactor:

Depends on what does the Action currently fired by the store means:

- If you are firing the action B every time action A is fired, the action creator (the code that calls action.defer) should fire A and then fire B
- If B is fired just when your store state meets some criteria, you could check for that previousState on the action create, and choose to fire B after A or not.